# Simple command to flat & unflatten JSON files

Tags: node.js, json, bash

I have flattened JSON files successfully using this Node.js/Bash command: `npx flat foo.json > bar-flat-output.json`.

What I'm looking for now is another simple & ready to use command to **unflatten** JSON files.

Comment: I'm not sure how this npx flat foo.json > bar-flat-output.json worked, but this flat module has flatten and unflatten methods. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat

Comment: @deechris27 Yes it has an unflatten function exported by name, but I can't execute it with **npx** :/

Comment: I suggest: `jq . foo.json`

Comment: can you provide an example of flattened and unflattened json ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you seem to be looking for a command to flatten and unflatten jsons in `bash`, and I guess it doesn't have to be `npx flat` as long as it works, I suggest a solution in jq.

The differences between the two version below are:

- version 1: The code is shorter
- version 2: The format of the flattened json is common

#### $INPUT

```json
{
   "key1": { "keyA": "valueI" },
   "key2": { "keyB": 2 },
   "key3": { "a": { "b": { "c": 2 } } },
   "key4": [1,[2,[3,4],5],6],
   "key5": true
}
```

#### flatten json - version 1

```sh
FLATTENED=$(jq '[ . as $json | paths(scalars) | . as $path | [., ($json | getpath($path))] ]' <<< "$INPUT")
```

```json
[
  [["key1","keyA"],"valueI"],
  [["key2","keyB"],2],
  [["key3","a","b","c"],2],
  [["key4",0],1],
  [["key4",1,0],2],
  [["key4",1,1,0],3],
  [["key4",1,1,1],4],
  [["key4",1,2],5],
  [["key4",2],6],
  [["key5"],true]
]
```

---

#### unflatten json - version 1

```sh
jq 'reduce .[] as $x (null; setpath($x[0]; $x[1]))' <<< "$FLATTENED"
```

```json
{
   "key1": { "keyA": "valueI" },
   "key2": { "keyB": 2 },
   "key3": { "a": { "b": { "c": 2 } } },
   "key4": [1,[2,[3,4],5],6],
   "key5": true
}
```

---

#### flatten json - version 2

```sh
FLATTENED=$(jq '
  def key: map(if type == "number" then "[\(tostring)]" else . end) | join(".");
  [ . as $json | paths(scalars) | . as $path | [key, ($json | getpath($path))] ]
  | reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x[0]] = $x[1])
' <<< "$INPUT")
```

```json
{
  "key1.keyA": "valueI",
  "key2.keyB": 2,
  "key3.a.b.c": 2,
  "key4.[0]": 1,
  "key4.[1].[0]": 2,
  "key4.[1].[1].[0]": 3,
  "key4.[1].[1].[1]": 4,
  "key4.[1].[2]": 5,
  "key4.[2]": 6,
  "key5": true
}
```

---

#### unflatten json - version 2

```sh
jq '
  to_entries
  | map(.key |= (split(".") | map(if test("^\\[[0-9]+\\]$"; "") then .[1:-1] | tonumber else . end)))
  | reduce .[] as $x (null; setpath($x.key; $x.value))
' <<< "$FLATTENED"
```

```json
{
   "key1": { "keyA": "valueI" },
   "key2": { "keyB": 2 },
   "key3": { "a": { "b": { "c": 2 } } },
   "key4": [1,[2,[3,4],5],6],
   "key5": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`jqg`](https://github.com/NorthboundTrain/jqg/) is a Bash script that can flatten and unflatten JSON using `jq`.

Using the following (randomly generated) JSON:

```
{
  "dicit": [
    "periculis commune temporibus eripuit",
    "potenti timeam venenatis an",
    292,
    "dissentias class nostrud duis",
    906.641
  ],
  "vestibulum": true,
  "veritus": [
    "consequat rationibus assueverit tota mnesarchum",
    "eligendi lobortis",
    false,
    "prodesset mauris accusam vivendum vel",
    "vero lacinia"
  ],
  "purus": {
    "ubique": "inciderint",
    "errem": "malesuada solet suspendisse dissentiet",
    "ridens": "regione",
    "omnes": {
      "dolorem": true,
      "repudiare": -118,
      "errem": [
        false,
        891.375,
        "dicta feugiat pede accusamus odio",
        "nobis",
        "vehicula option aperiam",
        "massa"
      ]
    }
  },
  "facilisi": 565
}
```

This flattens to:

```
$ jqg . /tmp/rnd.json
{
  "dicit.0": "periculis commune temporibus eripuit",
  "dicit.1": "potenti timeam venenatis an",
  "dicit.2": 292,
  "dicit.3": "dissentias class nostrud duis",
  "dicit.4": 906.641,
  "vestibulum": true,
  "veritus.0": "consequat rationibus assueverit tota mnesarchum",
  "veritus.1": "eligendi lobortis",
  "veritus.2": false,
  "veritus.3": "prodesset mauris accusam vivendum vel",
  "veritus.4": "vero lacinia",
  "purus.ubique": "inciderint",
  "purus.errem": "malesuada solet suspendisse dissentiet",
  "purus.ridens": "regione",
  "purus.omnes.dolorem": true,
  "purus.omnes.repudiare": -118,
  "purus.omnes.errem.0": false,
  "purus.omnes.errem.1": 891.375,
  "purus.omnes.errem.2": "dicta feugiat pede accusamus odio",
  "purus.omnes.errem.3": "nobis",
  "purus.omnes.errem.4": "vehicula option aperiam",
  "purus.omnes.errem.5": "massa",
  "facilisi": 565
}
```

`jqg` can also filter the flattened JSON, if desired:

```
$ jqg errem /tmp/rnd.json
{
  "purus.errem": "malesuada solet suspendisse dissentiet",
  "purus.omnes.errem.0": false,
  "purus.omnes.errem.1": 891.375,
  "purus.omnes.errem.2": "dicta feugiat pede accusamus odio",
  "purus.omnes.errem.3": "nobis",
  "purus.omnes.errem.4": "vehicula option aperiam",
  "purus.omnes.errem.5": "massa"
}
```

which would unflatten to:

```
$ jqg errem /tmp/rnd.json | jqg -u
{
  "purus": {
    "errem": "malesuada solet suspendisse dissentiet",
    "omnes": {
      "errem": [
        false,
        891.375,
        "dicta feugiat pede accusamus odio",
        "nobis",
        "vehicula option aperiam",
        "massa"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I am the author of `jqg`.